# How to print datetime according to user's time zone setting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, timezone

I'm user GAE's `ndb` for datastore, and have the `date` property defined like

```
class GuestMessage(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

So now I can print it easily with `e.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and get `2013-06-03 05:46:50`

But how can I print it like `2013-06-03 05:46:50 +0000` or `2013-06-03 13:46:50 +0800` according to user's time zone setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

datetime object has no tzinfo object. So please try this

```
import pytz
from pytz import timezone

query = GuestMessage.all().get()
current = query.date
user_tz = timezone('Asia/Singapore')
current = current.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(user_tz)
self.response.write(current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')) # 2013-05-22 19:54:14 +0800
self.response.write(current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')) # 2013-05-22 19:54:14 SGT
```

To find the timezone from request header:

```
county_code = self.request.headers['X-Appengine-Country'] # Return County code like SG, IN etc.
tz = pytz.country_timezones(county_code)
```

If you are getting `ImportError: No module named pytz`, Download the source from here: [pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz). Then move the pytz dir to the root of your app engine project

Comment: @narayanan Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell me how can I get the string like 'Asia/Singapore' from `self.request`

Comment: @narayanan I guess it's `pytz.country_timezones[country_code]` instead, isn't it? But interestingly I got 'ZZ' as country code in my test in [http://aappde.appspot.com/demo/request?foo=1&foo=2&bar=3] and [http://mylocationtest.appspot.com/], while 'ZZ' is not in the key list of the dict `pytz.country_timezones`. Anyway, Thank you for leading me move closer to the answer.

Comment: @Narayanan Maybe it's because of the proxy I am using. Shift to vpn, and I get 'US'.

Comment: @AdeYU `pytz.country_timezones[country_code]` & `pytz.country_timezones(country_code)` both will work.

Comment: @Narayanan Did I missed anything? pytz seems not available in python v2.7 as I got `Internal Server Error` for `ImportError: No module named pytz`

Comment: @AdeYU Is the pytz dir in the root of your app engine project? Download the source from here: [pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz). Then move the pytz dir to the root of your app engine project

Comment: @Nijo What about countries with 2 or more timezones? How would you detect which one the user is coming from?